# Parse a line of input into different types in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

this problem need print data types
https://codeforces.com/group/MWSDmqGsZm/contest/219158/problem/B

but he need inputs on just one line with space between each data type

this is my code , what's the problem

```
import java.util.Scanner
```

fun main(args:Array){

```
val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)

var a:Int=readLine()!!.toInt()
var b:Long=readLine()!!.toLong()
var c:Char=scanner.next().single()
var d:Float=readLine()!!.toFloat()
var e:Double=readLine()!!.toDouble()

println(a)
println(b)
println(c)
println(d)
println(e)
```

}

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "45 65896532145 a 45.23 65423.325"
> at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
> at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:660)
> at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:778)
> at Test_1Kt.main(test 1.kt:7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot parse the entire input as integer, as the input you expect is set of values with space between. Space itself cannot be parsed into Integer (this is what cause the exception)

To solve this, first, you need to split the input and parse each of the element. You can split it using kotlin built in function, i.e.

```
val input = readLine() ?: ""
val inputElement = input.split(" ")
```

Here, the `inputElement` is a string array that consist all of element from your input. Next, you need to parse each of the element by the `inputElement` index

```
val a:Int=inputElement[0].toInt()
val b:Long=inputElement[1].toLong()
val c:Char=inputElement[2].single()
val d:Float=inputElement[3].toFloat()
val e:Double=inputElement[4].toDouble()

println(a)
println(b)
println(c)
println(d)
println(e)
```